# CMS for developer site

Tags: templates, content-management-system

I want to build a web to get all my develop content together, get contact information... but I have very low level/imagination with design. Can you recommend me some good CSS web page or a CMS with a template?

Now I'm using blogger (http://www.asturdroid.net/), but it isn't the best alternative

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress is real nice........ especially if it is a self hosted one. There are a lot of nice themes available at themeforest. Also you can find syntax highlighter and other types of good plugins for wordpress

Comment: Wordpress is another blog CMS and it's not a good solution for a develop site.

Comment: @leinad-87 Wordpress can be used to create business websites, blogs and even for ecommerce sites(although i don't recommend that).... Just check out themeforest.net and you'll see

Answer (score 0):

For templates, themforest provides a wide range of them for many cms's. Joomla or Drupal would be a good solution for you, as they're very powerful PHP cms's